# Given the joint distribution of discrete random variables $x$ and $y$ , find the probability distribution of a "centred" version of $x$.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Discrete random variables $x$ and $y$ have the joint distribution:

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
 & \text{x=1} & \text{x=2} & \text{x=3} \\
\hline
y=1 & 3/12 & 1/12 & 3/12 \\
y=2 & 1/12 & 3/12 & 1/12 \\
\end{array}
$$

Let $x_c=x-E(x)=x-\mu_x$. (a centred version of $x$)

Find the probability distribution of $x_c$ and give the probabilities for each value.

I tried:

$E(x) = 2$

and $x_c$ has the values $-1, 0,  1$ for $x=1,2,3$, respectively.

Now I am stuck on finding the probabilities for the values of $x_c$.

Comment: $x_c=k\iff x-2=k\iff x=2+k$ so $P(x_c=k)=P(x=2+k)$

Comment: @drhab So the probabilities of each $x_c$ value are just the marginal probabilities of $x$?

Comment: $x_c$ is deduced from $x$ without any interference of $y$ so the distribution of $x_c$ is determined by the distribution of $x$.